# Microsoft Hyper-V Server with Linux Guest (Ubuntu 10.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I am running Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 and have 2 Linux guests running. I have noticed that if I increase the number of processors that are available to the Linux guest networking doesn't seem to work when booted into the OS. It does look like it was able to get an IP address from DHCP, but if I try to renew with dhclient ethx then it timesout saying that a DHCP server hasn't responded.
However, once I set the number of processors to one then it works perfectly.

Specs:
Legacy network adapter
Ubuntu 10.04

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To addon to Scott's comment, the solution is to enable the modules described in this article:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/enterprise_admin/archive/2010/03/09/linux-and-hyper-v-the-easy-way-brown-and-serve.aspx

After I ran through the steps everything worked great in Ubuntu.

In case those articles get taken down by someone or moved here are the steps:

Open /etc/initramfs-tools/modules with your favorite editor, add the following lines:
hv_vmbus
hv_storvsc
hv_blkvsc
hv_netvsc

Run the following as root:

`update-initramfs –u`

And reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the Linux Integration Component?  SMB should work even without them, but if you're running into issues like you described, it's likely from not having an enlightened Linux install.

Comment: The Linux Integration Components don't work out of the box on Ubuntu.

Comment: Not 'out of the box', but it will work without too much effort.  Here are some documented installs on Ubuntu 10.04 http://blogs.technet.com/b/enterprise_admin/archive/2010/03/09/linux-and-hyper-v-the-easy-way-brown-and-serve.aspx and http://blog.allanglesit.com/Blog/tabid/66/EntryId/53/Hyper-V-Guests-Ubuntu-10-04-Alpha-3-Synthetic-Devices.aspx.  I've installed it on 8.04 and it works well.  10.04 is supposed to be easier.